# alertDialog.setTitle cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog

Ok, let me begin by pointing out I'm an absolute beginner with java and android although I do know php and have dabbled with C, Python and a few other languages. Still, I'm a bit in over my head at the moment.

Anyway, I've created a new android project in eclipse, a bit of a hello world and I'd like a dialog to pop up with a cusom message and an OK button to dismiss the dialog.

I have imported AlertDialog into my action:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

and then instantiated an AlertDialog object:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

but then Eclipse throws up an error when I try and set a property on alertDialog:

```
alertDialog.setTitle = "Debug";
```

which prevents my app from compiling. I'm at a bit of a loss as I've looked at several guides online and can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

Also, I understand there are better ways of throwing up a dialog including putting them in an action, but I simply want this for some quick debugging feedback and to just learn what the hell is going on :)

Full source code for this activity is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3331622/activity.txt

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to remember the different syntax in java:

```
alertDialog.setTitle("Debug");
```

You are using a method in the class AlertDialog, not accessing a public field.

Comment: Hah, makes sense - I ought to pay better attention. Worked a treat, thanks.. I'd spent a couple of hours getting nowhere with that one.

Comment: Well said, Aleadam